# JavaFX memory consumption on window resizing operations

Tags: java, javafx

I have code that makes simple window without any functionality.
After the program started: process explorer says that it consumes ~50Mb ram.
But when user start to resizing window by dragging borders the consumption is rapidly grows (up to 500Mb). Consumption does not decrease after the cessation of the resizing.

What is the reason of such behavior?

```
// sample
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 300, 300);

        stage.setTitle("Leak");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can confirm whether it is a leak by requesting garbage collection. For example, add a button to your UI that, when clicked, runs `System.gc()` and then look at memory consumption. Alternatively, use VisualVM to request garbage collection on a running VM. VisualVM was likely installed on your system as part of your Java distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of java, where garbage collection is done, when it's done. At least in all cases where you use the defaults. Resizing a window fires some events and there is quite a lot going on the javafx, so do not worry to much about it. In doubt you can startup java's profiler and for fun, you can have a look at all the fancy stuff going on using debugging.